# MySQL Syntax Issue when using Accounts.UUID AND UUID =, with two tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax

I'm having issues when using this:

```
WARN com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Accounts.UUID = WarAccounts.UUIDAND Accounts.UUID = 'c7a00fe7-826d-46da-b4' at line 1
```

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Accounts,
  WarAccounts
WHERE
  Accounts.UUID = WarAccounts.UUID
  AND Accounts.UUID = ?
```

(Using prepared statements)

I'm very confused as to what is wrong with this to cause that issue, I've googled it but cannot find anything since this seems to be the correct way.

Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.58-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: _Accounts.UUID = WarAccounts._**UUIDAND** _Accounts.UUID =_

Comment: It isn't that, they are on separate lines.

Comment: Again, there isn't a required space between **UUIDAND**. Just read your exception WARNING... Print that `String` to console and see what is happening. If you get **UUID AND**, I cannot help you

Comment: Thank you but that did not work.

Comment: I'm sorry. I hope you'll get the proper answer. Good luck, pal

Answer (score 0):

Wild ass guess:

In C# i would do this:

```
string query = "SELECT *" + 
               "FROM MYTABLE" +
               "WHERE 1=1"
```

..to get your error..

Concat the string and you'll see the problem:

```
"SELECT *FROM MYTABLEWHERE 1=1"
```

The concatination should be:

```
string query = "SELECT * " + 
               "FROM MYTABLE " +
               "WHERE 1=1 "
```

(see the spaces at the end of every line?)

Comment: @Archie: Post your real code. You surely got a problem building your query.